# How do you enable keepAlive on ssl (wss) server with Ratchet?

Tags: php, ratchet

I have implemented a Ratchet WSS server like so:

```
$MyServer = new MyServer();

$app = new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
    new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
        $MyServer
    )
);

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$secure_websockets = new React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:6190', $loop);
$secure_websockets = new React\Socket\SecureServer($secure_websockets, $loop, [
    'local_cert' => '/path/to/cert.pem',
    'local_pk' => '/path/to/privkey.pem',
    'verify_peer' => false
]);

$secure_websockets_server = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer($app, $secure_websockets, $loop);

$secure_websockets_server->loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, function () use ($MyServer) {
    // loop
}

$app->enableKeepAlive($app->loop, 30);

$secure_websockets_server->run();
```

The server runs fine without `$app->enableKeepAlive($app->loop, 30);`, but fails once I add it.

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Ratchet\Http\HttpServer::enableKeepAlive() in /path/to/server-ssl.php:27
```

What is the correct way of wrapping the `keepAlive()`?

Comment: Did you somehow manage to do it? I'm having similar struggles

Answer (score 0):

enableKeepAlive() is a function of WsServer class, not HttpServer. Try the following code:

```
$app = new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer($MyServer);
```